Minimize sum of array sample from columns in 2D array with limitation on number of used row
TLDR; It seems to be a top k problem with dependency. Or a Knapsack Problem but the order matters.
If I have a 2D array with (N, M) shape.
I need to select L rows from it to be a (L, M) shape array SUB_M.
And for each column in SUB_M. I pick the smallest value in it and become a 1D (M) shape array ANS_M
My goal is to minimize the sum of ANS_M.
So for array like this.
[[  8   7   7   7   7   7   7   5   6]
 [  5   7   6   5   6   6   7   7   5]
 [  7   8   8   8   5   5   5   6   7]
 [  7   8   7   7   7   6   7   8   5]
 [  0   0 100 100 100 100 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100   0   0 100 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 100 100 100   0   0 100]]

I'll select row 1, 4, 5, 6.
The SUB_M would looks like this:
[[  5   7   6   5   6   6   7   7   5]
 [  0   0 100 100 100 100 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100   0   0 100 100 100 100]
 [100 100 100 100 100 100   0   0 100]]


And the ANS_M is this:
[  0   0   6   0   0   6   0   0   5]

So the sum of ANS_M is 17.
I think this problem is a little bit like a k sum problem.
But unlike k-sum problem. This problem can't be solved using max/min heap. Because in k-sum problem, two number can be compare directly. But in my problem, even if arr A is smaller than B and C in sum. Maybe sum of the combination of B and C can be smaller than A.
For example.
A = [ 5  5  5  5  5]
B = [ 0  0  0 99 99]
C = [99 99 99  0  0]

I was banging my head on wall on the problem. And I can't make ChatGPT to solve it.
I have a brute force solution is find all the combination C(N, C).
And for each combination arrays, I find the minimum along N and iterating through all the combination.
Is there any better way? Because the N and M could be pretty large.

Hi! Very interesting problem. This looks like it could be solved with dynamic programming, but not in a particularly obvious way. (PS: Don't ask ChatGPT to solve coding problems for you; there is nothing to be learned except laziness!!)

I tried to solve it using DP but failed. I can't get over the fact that whether a element in a row got sampled or not depends on other rows...

A random thought. Imagine you're in an M-dimensional space. Each row in the array is a point in this space. Choose one row. You start at the corresponding point. When you add a new row, you move to the point corresponding to the minimum of each coordinates. The goal is to move in the direction of vector [-1, -1, ..., -1]. So I guess a heuristic somewhat like A* could do pretty good.
